# PHP - Scraping javascript websites

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

I am trying to check the content of websites using php curl for any blacklisted keywords. But with curl I will not get the content generated by JS scripts. I have to scan  thousands of websites and efficiency is the main point here. I need to get js content. So far I came across Phantomjs-php. Are there any other js scripts which will take less resources that will work with php. I just need to get the html content. Any insights on this is much appreciated as I am new to getting JS generated content.

Thank you 
Lynn

Comment: I'm not sure about PHP libraries, but for python, I've been using js2py to do something similar. It's quite good, and much faster than selenium.

Comment: Thanks Loïc . But does it do something like how an headless browser will do? Execute js scripts and give me the content of the website? Python is new to me and I need to explore over there.

Comment: Kind of, except it's much faster than a headless browser. But you don't really have a browser view, you can just run any javascript script, so look into the variables, and things like that...
https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py

Comment: Thanks Loïc for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that [Codeception](https://codeception.com/) would do the trick for you.

You can configure it to work with a headless browser, just like phantom.js and puppeteer, and see your js generated content. A sample acceptance testing, which is what you want to do, would look like this:

```
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('username', 'davert');
$I->fillField('password', 'qwerty');
$I->click('LOGIN');
$I->see('Welcome, Davert!');
```

taken from: https://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests

Comment: Thanks Lucas . will check it out.